# How to use get_attachment call upon QueryResult (python cloudant) ?

Tags: python, cloudant

I've been trying to get attachment image data  from documents in Cloudant.
I can successfully do it once a document is selected (direct extract with _id, etc).

Now trying to do it in combination with "query" operation using selector, I run into trouble.

Here is my code.

```
targetName="chibika33"
targetfile="chibitest.png"

#--------------------------------------------------
# get all the documents with the specific nameField 
#--------------------------------------------------
myDatabase.create_query_index(fields = ['nameField'])
selector = {'nameField': {'$eq': targetName}}
docs = myDatabase.get_query_result(selector)

#--------------------------------------------------
# get the attachment files to them, save it locally
#--------------------------------------------------
count = 0
for doc in docs:
    count=count+1
    result_filename="result%03d.png"%(count)

    dataContent = doc.get_attachment(targetfile, attachment_type='binary')  
    dataContentb =base64.b64decode(dataContent)    
    with open(result_filename,'wb') as output:
        output.write(dataContentb)
```

Causes error as;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "view8.py", line 44, in <module>

   dataContent = doc.get_attachment(targetfile, attachment_type='binary')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_attachment'
```

So far, I've been unable to find any API for converting dict to document object  in the python-cloudant-document...[python-cloudant document]:  http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned structure from `get_query_result(...)` isn't an array of documents.

Try:

```
resp = myDatabase.get_query_result(selector)
for doc in resp['docs']:
    # your code here
```

See the docs at:

http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#cloudant.database.CloudantDatabase.get_query_result